# Get operating system and version number

Tags: c++, windows

I'm looking to get platform information such as the operating system and version number. In Python there is a [platform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) module which contains functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

[GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo)

[GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexw)

[GetNativeSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getnativesysteminfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[GetSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsysteminfo)

[NetWkStaGetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmwksta/nf-lmwksta-netwkstagetinfo)